# How to insert input result from Shiny to mySQL where clause?

Tags: r, rmysql

```
library(RMySQL)
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(

  pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel("Length"),
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("Length", "Enter Max Length below"),
      submitButton(text="Submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("tbTable"))
      )

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session)    
{
  myData <- reactive({
    req(input$length)



    dbhandle = dbConnect(MySQL() ,user = "xxx", password = "xxx123", dbname = "sakila", host = "localhost", port = 3306 )


    query = paste0("SELECT * FROM film WHERE length <=")


    res <- dbGetQuery(dbhandle,query)


    res

    dbDisconnect()

  })

  output$tbTable <- 
    renderTable(
      myData()
    )

} 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am hoping the value that users submit (the max.length) can use insert into the WHERE clause to filer correct results.(only the movies shorther than the max.length)

How can I do it?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: `paste0("select...")` with no other arguments is ... effectively a no-op. The first-cut (na&iuml;ve) approach would include `paste0(..., input$Length)`, though I don't recommend it. Second cut would be to bind parameters (see `DBI::dbBind`). Third cut would be to preface that with `req(input$Length)` so that you don't bind an input parameter that has not stabilized yet.

Comment: BTW: reconnecting every time an input parameter changes is fine as long as ... the input changes ***rarely***; time to connect can be non-trivial (depending on many things). You should probably instead look into `pool` and setting the connection in the `server` component (not within a reactive block).

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for your replies. How should I change my codes above? Could you kindly write them out? Thank you!

Comment: Really, I think the best way forward is for you to read RStudio's `pool` [basics](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/pool-basics.html) and [advanced](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/pool-advanced.html) for the `shiny`/`pool` side, and then [`?dbBind`](https://dbi.r-dbi.org/reference/dbbind) for binding parameters. The best I can do is regurgitate their words.

Comment: @r2evans After I checked the" pool" guidance page, it works! thanks again! :)